# Import CSV into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

I need import a `.csv` file into SQL Server.

I tried with bulk but that didn't work

[image: EXCEL]

I need create table with field left and column with field right .

Example

```
CREATE TABLE CARGA_TRAFICO_MED_MES_DATASET_IT
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    NAME VARCHAR(200),
    STATUS varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARGA_TRAFICO_MED_MES_DATASET_IT
VALUES("Job_Activity_8 (JOB JOB_CARGA_TRAFICO_DATASET_IT)", "status=1")
```

Comment: Your spreadsheet, if actually what you tried to bulk insert, won't work, because the data is all over the place.  If you just want to import the second and third columns, then save it as CSV and then bulk load that into SQL Server.

Comment: *"It won't work"*? What does that mean? What was the SQL you tried? Why didn't it work? Was there an error, unexpected behaviour, it crashed your server, something else entirely?

Comment: Your insert statement is only ever going to insert those values you specified with `VALUES`.  The Import/Export Wizard (and by extension, flat file import wizard in SSMS 2017) is a pretty good tool for importing *clean* CSV data. As @TimBiegeleisen noted, you need to clean this up first. All data in the *correct columns*, *only the columns you need* to put into the table, etc etc.